# Vulnerabilities problem using "npm install"

Tags: node.js, security, npm, package

I have installed an express server using `express coserver` command, then I used .npm install' command to install other node packages/dependencies, but I got this result:

```
                       === npm audit security report ===


                                 Manual Review
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance


  Low             Incorrect Handling of Non-Boolean Comparisons During
                  Minification

  Package         uglify-js

  Patched in      >= 2.4.24

  Dependency of   jade

  Path            jade > transformers > uglify-js

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/39


  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         uglify-js

  Patched in      >=2.6.0

  Dependency of   jade

  Path            jade > transformers > uglify-js

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/48


  Critical        Sandbox Bypass Leading to Arbitrary Code Execution

  Package         constantinople

  Patched in      >=3.1.1

  Dependency of   jade

  Path            jade > constantinople

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/568


  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         clean-css

  Patched in      >=4.1.11

  Dependency of   jade

  Path            jade > clean-css

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/785

found 4 vulnerabilities (3 low, 1 critical) in 194 scanned packages
  4 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

My `node --version` is `v10.15.0` and `express --version` is `4.16.1` and I use Windows 10. I don't know if other information is needed to put here but let me know that if so.

Comment: That happened because you were trying to install the dependencies of a project that specify packets with versions that have known vulnerabilities published. That means that NPM will request you to check if you really want to install those packets, even if there is vulnerable ones.

Comment: @IgorServulo: As I am a new learner of `nodeJS` and just following a video tutorial, don't know what to do to pass this problem?

Comment: You can run npm install packet --no-audit to install the version that you're trying to install, or run npm audit fix --force to update the packets that are vulnerable.

Comment: @IgorServulo: using `npm audit fix --force` I got `fixed 0 of 4 vulnerabilities in 194 scanned packages
  4 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated`

Comment: What is the difference between your suggestion and using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-audit-resolver` ?

Comment: `npm install packet --no-audit ` worked but when I search to find what exactly does this command I can not find anything about it?

Comment: the --no-audit option will install the packet without checking if it have a vulnerability or not. It will simply ignore this check and install the packet.

Answer (score 8):

reason: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade

fix:

1. npm uninstall jade
2. npm install pug

Answer (score 6):

> ***When the problem occurs***

You probably created the skeleton website by using the [express application generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html). This problem is faced when the app is created without specifying which view engine is to be used. `express <appname>` installs the packages below as dependencies (at the time of writing this post) and the problem is with the 'jade' package. '**jade**' is the default view engine for *express-generator* tool but **'jade' was renamed to 'pug'** and and jade is now **deprecated**.

```
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
"debug": "~2.6.9",
"express": "~4.16.1",
"http-errors": "~1.6.3",
"jade": "~1.11.0",
"morgan": "~1.9.1"
```

> ***how to fix***

- *with view engine*

use '**pug'** (renamed version of jade) as view engine

```
express myapp --view=pug
```

if 'pug' has low severity vulnerability, try

```
npm audit fix
```

- *without view engine*

generate app without view engine

```
exprees myapp --no-view
```

For more info about 'jade' package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade

Answer (score 0):

I faced this exact same error when I tried to install Express using `npx express-generator myapp` command.

To resolve this error, Following steps were taken:

1. Deleted my folder (myapp), in which I was trying to install express.
2. Start afresh.
3. Follow the step by step instruction given in https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html
4. `npm install` threw 1 Low severity vulnerability, which got later fixed by `npm audit fix`
5. Your Express.js should get installed successfully.