# Sandbox Bypass Leading to Arbitrary Code Execution - Jade has been renamed to pug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, npm, visual-studio-code

I wanna try to make a todo app with node.js, express.js and mongoDb. I install express and I followed these steps:

```
npm install -g express-generator

cd todo_api

npm install
```

got an error npm install.

npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
added 100 packages from 139 contributors and audited 101 packages in 5.432s
found 4 vulnerabilities (3 low, 1 critical)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

```
npm audit fix

npm audit
```

I tried npm audit fix and npm audit but problem is continue.

These are the audit outputs:
Critical        Sandbox Bypass Leading to Arbitrary Code Execution

Package         constantinople

Patched in      >=3.1.1

Dependency of   jade

Path            jade > constantinople

More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/568

Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service

Package         clean-css

Dependency of   jade

Path            jade > clean-css

More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/785

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with these two commands. I read the answer this topic

[Vulnerabilities problem using "npm install"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923270/vulnerabilities-problem-using-npm-install)

```
npm uninstall jade

npm install pug
```